# Using 'split feature' differently for some polygon features?

Tags: qgis

As a newbie for QGIS: Using QGIS 3.4 I like to split 'polygon' features. I tried many ways (via training, StackOverflow, etc).

Normally, using 'edit' and 'advanced editing' (plus snaps), I click outside my feature, then the 'first' snap on the feature, then the 'second' snap on the feature, then outside the feature and right click.

This method does not work in the following situation:

[image]

Can you help me doing the 'split feature' process that always works?

Comment: Just help in stead of comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you know the (more definitive) answer. Please write so. 
Be sure to have no feature selected - so deselect all.

Having the layer selected, edit on, snaps on, 'split feature' selected ... I now clicked

- Outside the feature
- On the feature (snapped) - starting-point to split the feature
- On the feature (snapped) - ending-point to split the feature
- Outside the feature
- On the feature (snapped) - next starting point ...

Etc. Now the feature was split twice. And doing a further single split worked also.

Why is that?